# How do I clear Cursor.Clip in C# and allow the cursor to move freely again?

Tags: c#, clip, mouse-cursor

I am trying to lock the cursor into the form, this is for a mouse locker application, I am trying to dispose the cursor so it will reset the `Cursor.Clip` when they unlock it.

So far I have:

```
Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(x +8, y +30, Size.Width -16, Size.Height -38);
```

That works fine.

But I cannot figure out how to clear the clip when they unlock it.
I have tried `Cursor.Dispose();` But that doesn't work.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Clip` to a `Rectangle` that contains the screen's dimensions.

```
Cursor.Clip = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
```

Of course, this won't work with dual monitor setups, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 13):

actually the idea is to just set it to a new rectangle

```
Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle();
```

It works regardless of the situation.

Comment: Times like this, the accepted answer isn't the correct one. Thanks for the post, I couldn't remember how I did this years ago

Answer (score 2):

Try this: when your application starts, get the value of `Cursor.Clip` and save it as the unclipped value. Then when you want to reset the clip, assign the unclipped value.

**UPDATE**: [In this page](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18681) it says that to unclip the cursor in VB.NET, it is enough to do `Cursor.Clip=Nothing`. But this is strange since Rectangle is a structure and thus it can't be set to null. So in C#, maybe it would be `Cursor.Clip=Rectangle.Empty` or `Cursor.Clip=default(Rectangle)`?