# Reset Cursor.Clip

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse

I'm trying to lock the cursor into a PictureBox once the MouseEntered event is fired.

I want to cancel this upon typing Ctrl + Enter (Or another shortcut, if there is a best practice in regards to that)

I'm trying to clear the Clip in the way mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1905139/1233949) but I think my MouseEnter is continually killing any chance I have to leave.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Best practice is to only capture or clip the mouse for a temporary operation. Typically this is capture/clip on mouse down and restore on mouse up. Clipping the mouse and requiring a key-press to release is rare. I can only think of one example: Virtual Machine applications, and they typically use Ctrl+Alt to leave and Ctrl+G to enter.

Comment: That's exactly my application. A Remote Desktop Viewer. :) I'll keep those shortcuts in mind! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking here because of the mention of your `MouseEnter` event that you didn't show. Assuming you'll take care of that yourself, I actually disagree with the accepted answer in that thread. Decompiling `System.Windows.Forms` you have:

```
internal static Rectangle ClipInternal
{
    get
    {
        NativeMethods.RECT rECT = default(NativeMethods.RECT);
        SafeNativeMethods.GetClipCursor(ref rECT);
        return Rectangle.FromLTRB(rECT.left, rECT.top, rECT.right, rECT.bottom);
    }
    set
    {
        if (value.IsEmpty)
        {
            UnsafeNativeMethods.ClipCursor(null);
            return;
        }
        NativeMethods.RECT rECT = NativeMethods.RECT.FromXYWH(value.X, value.Y, value.Width, value.Height);
        UnsafeNativeMethods.ClipCursor(ref rECT);
    }
}
```

Which seems to indicate that passing `Rectangle.Empty` is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** : According to [this](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/MouseClipping.aspx) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/375046/The-Cursor-Clip-Property): Set to empty rectangle:

```
 Cursor.Clip = Rectangle.Empty;
```

Comment: That was the accepted answer in the link DTI-Matt gave. It's also the wrong answer, try the one with the most votes.