# How to release captured (clipped) cursor in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse, ironpython

I was trying to implement [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.clip?view=net-5.0) with IronPython.
I succeeded to capture the cursor using this method:

```
def MoveCursor(self):
    #Set the Current cursor, move the cursor's Position,
    #and set its clipping rectangle to the form.
    if self.MouseLocked == False:
        self.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current.Handle)
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = System.Drawing.Point(self.Cursor.Position.X - 50, self.Cursor.Position.Y - 50)
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Clip = System.Drawing.Rectangle(self.Location, self.Size)
        self.MouseLocked = True
    elif self.MouseLocked == True:
        self.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current.Handle)
        #System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = System.Drawing.Point(self.Cursor.Position.X - 50, self.Cursor.Position.Y - 50)
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Clip = None
        self.MouseLocked = False
```

I tried using a class variable to toggle the capturing but it doesn't work as I expected.
How do I release the mouse? Which method or event do I need to use?

update:
I tried using self.Cursor.Dispose(), but that just made my cursor invisible :D, kinda funny, but not what I needed.

Comment: How does your question, specifically, relate to the [tag:c#] tag?

Comment: it's a dotnet question, c# is the "flagman" language of the dotnet "family". If you follow the link of the example it's the C# documentation. The example there is in c#.

Comment: Let me rephrase; you question needs focus. As it stands, you've blasted us with ironpython code and said "*it doesn't work as expected*". I understand what C# is, and realize that the example itself is pure C#, but the problem is that future readers looking for your question won't be able to immediately determine this. I *recommend* summarizing the snippet from the MSDN link you've provided to demonstrate, more clearly what you're trying to do. Additionally, now that I've had sleep, I'm posting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Releasing*" the clipping of the cursor is called "*clearing*" from a technical aspect, and will yield better search results. There are *many* other examples ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805260/how-do-i-clear-cursor-clip-in-c-sharp-and-allow-the-cursor-to-move-freely-again) is one) on the web dealing with this exact issue in dedicated C#, and doing the same with ironpython is no different.

As you review [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.clip?view=net-5.0), the first sentence in particular *implicitly* answers your question (emphasis mine):

> *The following code example creates a cursor from the Current cursor's Handle, **changes its position and clipping rectangle***.

To *clear* a previously set position and clipping rectangle, you need to set the `Clip` property to a *new*, empty `Rectangle`:

```
Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle();
```

This effectively *clears* the position and clipping rectangle of the cursor. Your particular case would place it in your `elif` block:

```
elif self.MouseLocked == True:
    ...
    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Clip = new System.Drawing.Rectangle()
    ...
```